# Creating objects in a foreach loop

Tags: c#

I have some code that creates objects in a foreach loop.  So:

```
private IEnumerable<StrongTypeResult> ConvertResults(List<Object> results)
    {
     return results.Select(result => new StrongTypeResult(result)).ToList();       
    }
```

FYI, StrongTypeResult is a struct.  Since each `new StrongTypeResult(result)` object is allocated on the stack, if there are a large amount of objects to create, am I going to run into a stackoverflow issue?  Would it be better to make `StrongTypeResult` a class?

Comment: I don't believe your code does what you think it does.

Comment: Are you missing a `yield` statement in your code sample? Edit: Actually I'm not even really sure what's going on here.

Comment: I agree with @Chris you are probably missing a yield. As far as your other question, it doesn't appear that you have any stack constructed items here, and even if you did, the struct is wrapping an `Object` that is a reference to some item that we have no idea what it is. Basically, I would not be worried about a stackoverflow here. I would be more worried that this code is not doing what it should.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you don't need a foreach here. Select already returns an IEnumerable of the desired type. You don't need a ToList also. Transforming delegate will be called when foreaching the IEnumerable on the client.

```
private IEnumerable<StrongTypeResult> ConvertResults(List<Object> results)
{
 return results.Select(result => new StrongTypeResult(result));
}
```

Structs are created on stack when you assign a struct to a variable. If you store them in a list or in an array,they will be on heap.

Please learn about differences between reference types, and value types, such as structs.
Generally, structs are copied on assigning to another variable.

Answer (score 1):

If you want just to run into the `StackOveFlowException` it is enough to create infinitive recursive call

```
public void DeadLoop()
{
   this.DeadLoop();
}
```

Comment: Depending on platform and optimizations, this may just result in an infinite loop due to tail-recursion optimization.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will be better if you use classes. There is no point in moving lot of data around.